# How to Control where a form loads

Tags: vb.net

This is going to be the first of many questions I am sure.

I am starting to create an application in VB.net and I am not super familiar with the language yet. I am trying to design an application based off of a system tray icon and by that I mean, when you launch the application, there should be no initial form that loads, just the icon in the system tray.

From there I need to do two things. I would like "on mouse-over" to pop-up the form right above the system tray and "on double-click" have it open in the middle of the computer screen.

I am successful in using "static" placement {`Me.Location = New Point(800, 390)`}

I can get the windows/forms to open where I want them to, but the problem is when I change to a different computer they don't open in the correct location. I need a way to make sure the forms open in correct location no matter the screen resolution.

Can anyone recommend what I should Google to learn more about form placement or maybe even a link. Being so new to the language, my Google attempts have failed and I am needing more direction and a little hand holding until I get the terminology down and an idea of what I am looking for,...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamically place your form based off the desktop size, check out:

```
SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width   
SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height
```

...and move your form based on these dynamic values. e.g.

```
Me.Location = New Point(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width - Me.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height - Me.Height)
```

For more information about VirtualScreen, check out MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.virtualscreen.aspx

VirtualScreen will give you the combined size and width of multiple monitors, so as an alternate, you could also simply look at the primary screen, e.g.

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width
Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height
```

Comment: This is along the lines of exactly what I am looking for. I will begin research and I can't thank you enough !

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Me.CenterToScreen`To center it to the users screen and as far as i know that is the best you can do

Comment: Well, I am needing it to appear right above the taskbar.
Using : Me.Location = New Point( _
        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 1000, _
        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
and then setting a timer with :
        If i = 2000 Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
        If Not Me.Location.Y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - 410 Then
            Me.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y - 2)
        End If
I can get it to kinda work... Should I be using a different language? 
I know what I need is possible, I am basing it off of another .net application.

Answer (score 0):

In form properties there is a property **StartUpPosition** set it to **CenterScreen**